# Chip Cards: как получить UID карты используя APDU комманды

Tags: nfc, банковские-карты

Здравствуйте!

В данный момент столкнулся с новой для меня проблемой взаимодействия Безконтактной Чипованной Карты и Карт-ридера через NFC канал (ISO14443, ISO 7816 Part 4).

Мне нужно достать идентификатор карты, который позволит различить одну карту от другой (я так  понимаю мне нужен PAN или что-то типа PAN sequence).

Карта позитивно отзывается на команду

```
00:a4:04:00:0e:32:50:41:59:2e:53:59:53:2e:44:44:46:30:31:00
```

т.е. у меня есть AID карты.

Вопрос состоит в том, что нужно составить APDU-комманду (или даже скорее всего последовательность APDU-комманд), которые позволят вытянуть информацию с тэгом '5A', где прячется информация о PAN.

В связи с этим конкретизирую свои вопросы:

1)Прежде всего хотелось бы прояснить для себя 'card-reader workflow', т.к. до сего момента примеры, которые я видел и пытался заюзать заключались в выполнении какой-то одной конкретной команды, f.e.

```
00:CA:00:5A:00
```

response -> `6A:88`

Имхо, там должно быть что-то 'открыл ресурс/файл'->'считал нужную запись'->'закрыл ресурс'?

2) Теги, которые являются указателями на хранение конкретной информации, их необходимо использовать в P1-P2 или они служат полезной нагрузкой L за блоком CLA-INS-P1-P2?

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы достать значение под тегом '5A' надо выполнить следующую последовательность APDU-команд:

1) Если не знаем AID аплета на карте, то выполняем следующую команду, если знаем то данный шаг можно пропустить (2PAY.SYS.DDF в моем случае)

```
00:a4:04:00:0e:32:50:41:59:2e:53:59:53:2e:44:44:46:30:31:00
```

2) Потом выбираем данное приложение (SELECT APPLICATION)

```
00 A4 04 00 AID-Lenth AID
```

3) Запрашиваем GET PROCESSING OPTIONS

```
80 A8 00 00 02 83 00 00
```

4) Читаем READ RECORD

```
00 B2 01 14 00
```

В ответе среди потока байтов и будет таг "5А" со значением PAN. Для парсинга ответа я использовал сервис https://www.emvlab.org/tlvutils

В связи с тем, что есть необходимость программно парсить ответ, нет ли каких java-библиотек для парсинга R-APDU?